# git commit -a did not work

Tags: git

I am kind of a newbie with Git, and I encounter some problems already...
I did clone a repository (on BitBucket) to my machine, and modified a file 'Makefile' and created 3 new ones (c_file, gma.txt and ded_mpi.dat).
Then, I typed to commit these add/changes to the master repository: `commit -a` and I wrote a message in the text editor)

I have 2 issues here. First, I thought this would commit my changes to the master rep, but it doesn't (I checked it by cloning the master version: my changes are not included).
However, in the rep on my machine, `git log` contains my message...

I think I missed something with the way Git works :)
`git diff` prints nothing.

2nd issue:

`git status` prints:

```
# On branch master 
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. 
# 
# Untracked files: 
# (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) 
# 
#   c_file  
#   gma.txt 
#   ded_mpi.dat 
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Files c_file, gma.txt et ded_mpi.dat were committed but not added...I thought `commit -a` did both 'commit' and 'add'... ??

On the other, nothing in the status about the pre-existing Makefile that I modified...

As you can see, I would need a hand :)

If anyone could help me understand what's going on, it would be great!

Cheers

Comment: @eis How does that solve the issue?  The user simply needs to go through each file, and if he wants to omit it, add it to .gitignore

Answer (score 4):

1.I think you forgot push your commit, like "git push origin master"

2."git commit -a" don't add new file, just commit modified and delete files, you need use "git add ." to prepare commit.

Comment: Hum ok. I will try what you suggest, thanks. Should I "delete" my previous commit in order not to have it in double in the commit history? How could I do this plz?

Comment: Yes, pushing the commit to master will solve this error if he already added and committed everything he was concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

First, pay attention to the status message, it's telling you there are untracked files that haven't been added yet and can be done so with

```
git add .
```

now, to fix your commit so you don't push 2 commit objects, you can "amend" the current commit object with your newly added files like this:

```
git commit --amend
```

now if you do `git status` you'll have a single commit object ready to push to the remote.

I would strongly advise getting some basics under your belt. Go see [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/) for a good starter.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine! and thx for the tuto link as well ;)

Comment: @Mark When I do git commit --amend, it just shows me the last commit message.  It does not change anything the next time I run git status

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky as i said in my post, you have to add files first before commit ammending. running git commit --amend allows you to change the current commit object, and offers you a chance to edit the status message. you don't have to change it, but if you had done `git add ...` before it, then the commit will have changed because of the changed files. check the commit ids. if they don't change then you haven't added any changed files or changed the commit message. changing either of these will change the commit object (the status forms part of the commit too), and thus its id.

Answer (score 0):

first go with : git add .
then : git commit -m"commet message here"

done

Comment: Don't forget to format your code